# TWITTER API error 220 -: twitteroauth

Tags: php, api, twitter

Good evening all,

I am using the PHP code from https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth

The login works perfectly but when trying to post a status to Twitter i get the following error:

```
stdClass Object ( [errors] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [code] => 220 [message] =>      Your credentials do not allow access to this resource. ) ) )
```

I am using the following code:

```
session_start();
require_once('twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php');
require_once('config.php');

$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $_SESSION['oauth_token'],
$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']);

$token_credentials = $connection->getAccessToken($_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']);


$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $token_credentials['oauth_token'],
$token_credentials['oauth_token_secret']);

$account = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');
$status = $connection->post('statuses/update', array('status' => 'Text of status here'));
```

I have followed the same instructions as the website. Where am i going wrong?

Comment: Is your application asking permission to post on behalf of a user?

Comment: yes it is. They basically sign in. On return to the site a post is generated and they post to their profile. The posting is what is causing the error

Comment: what does the $account = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials'); return ?

Comment: Might be a good idea to read this : https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth It seems you are doing the requests as application level authentication and not as the user request. error 220 raises when you try to post as a user when in fact your posting as an app only.

Go back and separate the steps into a callback that writes the access token and dont request it on the same page. Your not verifying you actually got an access token. I suggest you break your code to a callback page requesting the token [ Removing the request tokens ] and passing to the post page.

Answer (score 0):

In your case do you have to create an api on twitter ?
https://apps.twitter.com/
If you did, check the configuration of your api.
this link could be helpful.
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/faq